# Data type conversion in Postfix evaluation

Tags: c

Why do we pass exp[i]- '0' in the push if exp[i] is a digit but don't do the same in case of operator i.e, val2 operator val1 -'0'. I guess it's related to ascii say we want to insert 2 then ascii of char 2 - ascii of char 0= 2 in decimal and we push it in the stack(which is int array but the argument is char op) but we don't do the same if its an operator. Also if we are receiving the second argument in push as "char" op then why do we need to convert it into ascii and it also doesn't affect the output if we change the char to int op in the second argument of push?
[a link] http://geeksquiz.com/stack-set-4-evaluation-postfix-expression/

```
void push(struct Stack* stack, char op)
{
stack->array[++stack->top] = op;
}

int evaluatePostfix(char* exp)
{
struct Stack* stack = createStack(strlen(exp));
int i;
if (!stack) return -1;
for (i = 0; exp[i]; ++i)
{
    // If the scanned character is an operand or number,
    // push it to the stack.
    if (isdigit(exp[i]))
        push(stack, exp[i] - '0');

    //  If the scanned character is an operator, pop two
    // elements from stack apply the operator
    else
    {
        int val1 = pop(stack);
        int val2 = pop(stack);
        switch (exp[i])
        {
         case '+': push(stack, val2 + val1); break;
         case '-': push(stack, val2 - val1); break;
         case '*': push(stack, val2 * val1); break;
         case '/': push(stack, val2/val1);   break;
        }
    }
}
return pop(stack);
}
int main()
{
char exp[] = "231*+9-";
printf ("Value of %s is %d", exp, evaluatePostfix(exp));
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do we pass `exp[i]- '0'` in the push if exp[i] is a digit but don't do the same in case of operator

This is because the value of `digitChar-'0'` expression is meaningful: it represents a numeric value of your digit, because numeric codes of digit characters are sequential. In contrast, subtracting anything from an operator does not give you any advantages, because numeric codes of operators are *not* sequential.

> Also if we are receiving the second argument in push as `char op` then why do we need to convert it into ascii

We don't - `op` remains in the same encoding that your system uses.

> and it also doesn't affect the output if we change the char to int op in the second argument of push?

It works because we use `char op` for its numeric value. When you make an assignment to `array` inside `struct Stack`, the compiler converts `int` to the element type of the `array`, so there is no difference.

Comment: char c[]={1,2,3,4};int z=c[1]-'0';printf("%d",z); It prints -46
but u said digitchar - '0' should give us numeric values in that case it should give us 2(50-48)

Comment: @Stack That's not what I said. I said that if you do `char c[]={'1','2','3','4'};` you would get the numeric value. `{1,2,3,4}` in your examples are not digit character codes (they are not even printable on many systems).

Comment: for the struct the compiler converts it implicitly.. From the input array when we pass exp[1] without - '0' does it evaluate to 50 and does exp[1]== '1' or 1 ?

Comment: @Stack `char exp[] = "231*+9-"` is a shorter equivalent of `char exp[] = {'2','3','1','*','+','9','-','\0'}`. Try it out.

Comment: what if we want to evaluate double or triple digit?
I included space btn operators and operands in the input array
[20 30 10 * + 90 -] should evaluate to 230 but it giving 0

Comment: @Stack This requires a different approach your line `push(stack, exp[i] - '0');` has to become a loop that copies all digits until a space, and converts them to an `int`, say, by calling `atoi` on the copied array of digit characters. Alternatively, you could implement your own digit-by-digit conversion in the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `char` variable holds the *characters* based on their corresponding ASCII value.

To convert the ASCII representation `'1'` to integer value `1`, you need to subtract the ASCII value of `0`, [`'0'`] from the `char` value. Then you can perform the arithmetic operations, `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` on those `int` values.

For example, `'5'` has the ASCII value of 53. Subtracting ASCII value of `'0'` [48] leaves you with (53-48) = 5, as integer.

That is why, for the digits [note the use of `isdigit(exp[i])`], `'0'` is subtracted. However, the operators does not need this, because they are not being used as operands.

Related reading: [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: char p=2;
int a=c;
printf("%d",a) prints 2
can u explain how this works bcoz 2(and not '2') is not a char but we are assigning it to a char?

Comment: @stack use `'2'` and check. :-)

Comment: @stack also for char, the format specifier is `% c`

Comment: I know that i was just checking what if we assign an integer value to a char how is it evaluated(i.e, do we take the ascii value of 2 or what)? Also if we then assign c to an integer and print int a using %d it prints out 2.

Comment: @Stack let me give you a simple example, suppose `char c = 9`, then using `%d` it will print `9`, using `%c` it will print a `tab` [empty space]. OTOH, `char c = '9'`, using `%d` it will print `57`, using `%c` it will print `9`. Hope it's clear now. :-)